# TDS Package Installer Time out Issues in Sitecore 7.2

Tags: package, installation, sitecore, tds

We have been trying to install a sitecore upgrade package created from TDS and see that it always times out.We have database is different machine and Sitecore instance in different machine.Any Idea on what could be the issue behind this?

Entry from Log file:

[image]

We also tried to install the same package through /sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx .In this way we are able to install successfully but it took 1 hour 20 minutes to install a package having 1500 items which is 1500 KB.

We tried to do that on a different database server and we were able to install but not on this particular server.Can this be a case of poor database performance.How can we resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you check a few things? 1. Make sure the Sitecore.Update.dll version matches the version of Sitecore you have installed. For this go to the Sitecore download page and look for update installation wizard there. 2. Try installing the patch from the server itself. Trying to install the package using DNS address may have some issues. This was the case with us.

Comment: Did you reach a solution ? I am experiencing similar issues, even when  long timeouts have been applied.

Comment: Nope still the same:(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase request timeout by this setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3000000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If problem is only in slow performance of your machine then it should help.

However I recommend to investigate deeply why it works so slowly.